# Why is $(R \otimes R \otimes \bar{R} \otimes \bar{R})_1= (R \otimes \bar{R} \otimes R\otimes \bar{R})_1 $?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a non-selfconjugate representation $R$ and its conjugate representation $\bar{R}$ of a group $G$, why do we have
$$(R \otimes R \otimes \bar{R} \otimes  \bar{R})_1= (R  \otimes \bar{R}  \otimes R\otimes  \bar{R})_1 ,$$ where  the subscript $1$ means that we only consider the $1$ dimensional part of the tensor product. (In general we have $R \otimes \bar R= 1 \oplus \ldots$ and here we are only interested in the group invariant, i.e. the part of the product that transforms as the one-dimensional representation)

Maybe even the more general result

$$R \otimes R \otimes \bar{R} \otimes  \bar{R} = R  \otimes \bar{R}  \otimes R\otimes  \bar{R} ,$$

which I checked explicitly for a few cases.

Comment: By the $)_1$ you mean? ... also the $\otimes$ is just the tensor product right?

Comment: @AlecTeal yes $\otimes $ is just the tensor product and $)_1$ means that from the many representations that appear in the tensor products $(R \otimes R \otimes \bar{R} \otimes  \bar{R}) = R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus \ldots$ , we only consider the part that transforms as the one-dimensional representation.

Comment: I've starred this as a note to "check back later" (along with hundreds of others....) if you don't get an answer, I can have a go tonight. Please send me a comment should you get no answer.

Comment: @AlecTeal Alright, thanks a lot!

Comment: The tensor product is symmetric. There is an obvious map from $V_1\otimes V_2$ to $V_2\otimes V_1$, and it is not hard to check that this is an isomorphism for representations of groups.